# How to pass url to php class constructor

Tags: php

I want to include this https://github.com/emotionLoop/visualCaptcha-PHP code as a library.

So I'm including class from outside folder like this:

```
<?php printCaptcha('contact_us_form_vc',$_FORM_TYPE,$_FIELD_NAME); ?>

function printCaptcha($formId = NULL, $type = NULL, $fieldName = NULL) {
    require_once(SITE_ROOT . '/visualCaptcha/inc/visualcaptcha.class.php');
    $visualCaptcha = new \visualCaptcha\Captcha($formId, $type, $fieldName);
    $visualCaptcha->show();
}
```

Inside class there are variables I want to pass from my function:

```
private $htmlClass = 'visualcaptcha.class.html.php';
    public static $imagesPath = 'images/visualcaptcha/';
    public static $audiosPath = 'audio/visualcaptcha/';
    public static $imageFile = 'image.php';
    public static $audioFile = 'audio.php';
```

Any ideas how to pass them?

What I did:

```
function printCaptcha($formId = NULL, $type = NULL, $fieldName = NULL, $htmlClass = NULL) {
    require_once(SITE_ROOT . '/visualCaptcha/inc/visualcaptcha.class.php');
    $visualCaptcha = new \visualCaptcha\Captcha($formId, $type, $fieldName, $htmlClass);
    $visualCaptcha->show();
}
```

And than inside class:

```
public function __construct( $formId = NULL, $type = NULL, $fieldName = NULL, $accessibilityFieldName = NULL, $htmlClass = NULL )
```

And added:

```
if ( ! is_null($htmlClass) ) {
            $this->htmlClass = $htmlClass;
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Is there any mention of how to update these in the manual?  The `public static` ones can be updated with `Captcha::$imagesPath`.  The `private` one cannot be updated, unless there is a method to do so, or you modify the class to allow it.

Comment: @RocketHazmat no mention in documentation at all! I couldn't even pass private one.

Comment: as RocketHazmat said there is no way (as far as I know) to update the private ones without any method. You may, however, add your own method to the class to access to the private variable and change it.. For the public STATIC ones just use the standard syntax Classname::$variable ...

Comment: That's what `private` means.  You can *only* access private variables from inside the class itself.

Comment: @briosheje quick example with 1 variable would be nice :)

Comment: @salivan: all right, i'll try something with the comment, even though I'm pretty sure I didn't completely understand where the problem is :)

Comment: @briosheje in short, I want to use that code as a library that I can access from anywhere within application. At the moment I've to hardcode urls inside class, thus cannot use it as true droppable library.

Comment: @salivan: I've posted what I meant above by "method to replace a private variable", hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments, the quick example about accessing a private variable with a method can be this one:

Assuming you have a class with a private variable:

```
class testClass {
   private $privateVar;
}
```

And you want to change its value, you may do something like that:

```
class testClass {
  private $privateVar;

  public function updatePrivateVar($value) {
     $this->privateVar = $value;
  }
}
```

So, assuming you have your variables:

```
private $htmlClass = 'visualcaptcha.class.html.php';
public static $imagesPath = 'images/visualcaptcha/';
public static $audiosPath = 'audio/visualcaptcha/';
public static $imageFile = 'image.php';
public static $audioFile = 'audio.php';
```

and assuming you want to update them, for the public ones you just need to use this syntax:

```
Classname::$publistaticvar = $newValue;
```

Example:

```
Captcha::$htmlClass = $htmlClass;
```

While for the private ones, assuming you have a method like the one suggested above, just create an object of your Captcha class (if you don't already have created one):

```
$captcha = new Captcha;
```

and use its method to change the private variable value:

```
$captcha->updatePrivateVar($newValue);
```

I'm not sure it is exacly what you want to do, but from what we've been discussing into the comments it should be the case.

hope it helps!

Comment: *ah, molto buono anche*. Yes, I do speak (some) Italian ;) There should be more people like you who don't care much for rep points (*although the points do serve a purpose*) but to actually "help". Credit is given where credit is due. `$credit="+1";` ;) ciao.

Comment: *Plus,* I have a hard time comprehending classes, and your answer helped me to understand them that much more.

Comment: @Fred-ii- : Well, thanks! Just trying to do everyone's job here in stackoverflow.